# JS / jQuery eq() - array

Tags: javascript, jquery, циклы

Возможно ли вместо привычного цикла, на подобии этого:

```
for (i = 0; 0 < div.length; i++) {
$(div:eq(i).somethingtodo();
}
```

Выполнить замену в элементах, где `eq()` совпадает со значением в массиве? К примеру `$(div:eq(array(0, 1, 2))).somethingtodo()` - следовательно работам с `div`, с `eq()` от 0 до 2?

Comment: конкретно этот цикл повесит вам браузер на дооолго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eq() - принемает только индекс. Как вариант можно воспольсоватися each():

```js
$("div").each((i, item) => {
  $(item).css({
    "color": "red"
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $div = $('.div'),
  arr = ['0', '2', '4'],
  cr = arr.toString();

for (var i in arr) $div.eq(arr[i]).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #0001;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```